# Add other classes to li elements

Tags: html, css

I have a list of elements like

```
<ul id="Menus">
   <li>Home</li>
   <li>About</li>
   <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

And few CSS classes like

```
.classOne
{
   height:20px;
   background-color:#f00; 
   background-image:url('icons.png');
   background-repeat:no-repeat; //and many other style properties
}

.classTwo
{
   width:50px;
   border:1px solid #ccc; //and many other style properties
}

#Menus li
{
   display:inline-block;
   list-style:none;
}
```

Now how can I apply `.ClassOne` and `.ClassTwo` on my #Menus li? I know I can do this by this code

```
 .classOne, #Menus li
 .classTwo, #Menus li
```

But is there any other way to do this except above code because I got many other li and other elements so I will have to keep adding? following above code, it creates a long list like.

```
.classOne, #Menus li, #otherMenus li, #bgImages li, #etc li, #etc
```

And in then if sometimes if I have to change some thing then it create problem. I just want to apply my `.classOne` and `.classTwo` on any li elements not by adding like above. Is there any CSS trick?

Comment: Are you talking about combining the selectors on css or javascript to add the new classes to the li elements?

Comment: @AnilMaharjan Last line states he wants it with CSS tricks OP.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use a CSS preprocessor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org). They allow you to reuse pieces of code in your css.

What you might do in LESS would be this:

```
.some-css
{
   width:50px;
   border:1px solid #ccc; //and many other style properties
}

#Menus li
{
   display:inline-block;
   list-style:none;
   .some-css;
}
```

the style for #Menus li would become:

```
#Menus li
{
   display:inline-block;
   list-style:none;
   width:50px;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: so what's making .some-css work if I have to manually add properties to all my elements?

Comment: a preprocessor is like a language on top of your css. You need a compiler for it. If you can change the HTML the option James Donnelly provided might be easier to implement. To learn more about preprocessors you should check out the links I've provided in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could simply introduce a new class on your `ul` elements:

```html
<ul id="Menus" class="newClass">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>

<ul id="otherMenus" class="newClass">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Then simply:

```css
.classOne, .newClass li {
    ...
}

.classTwo, .newClass li {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you would not want to added the required class on the HTML li elements directly?

For example:

```
<ul id="Menus">
   <li class="classOne classTwo">Home</li>
   <li class="classOne classTwo">About</li>
   <li class="classOne classTwo">Contact</li>
</ul>
```